# Error al instalar laravel 6

Tags: laravel

Hola buen día estoy queriendo instalar laravel 6 pero me da el siguiente error:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs>laravel new blog --auth
Crafting application...

In CurlFactory.php line 200:

  cURL error 28: Failed to connect to 190.195.101.53 port 1080: Timed out (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl
  -errors.html)
```

Gracias de antemano el soporte.

**No funciona 
composer global update laravel/installer**

C:\xampp\htdocs>Laravel new my-test-app

Crafting application...

In CurlFactory.php line 200:

cURL error 28: Failed to connect to 190.195.101.53 port 1080: Timed out (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

new [--dev] [--auth] [-f|--force] [--] []

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

MI VERSIÓN DE COMPOSER INSTALLER

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

¿Qué versión del installer de Laravel tienes?

Intenta actualizarlo y realizar la tarea de nuevo:

```
composer global update laravel/installer
composer global show
```

Y deberías de ver:
laravel/installer             vX.X.x Laravel application installer.

```
laravel new my-test-app --auth
```

o en su versión larga para ver exactamente dónde puede fallar:

```
Laravel new my-test-app
cd my-test-app
composer require laravel/ui --dev
php artisan ui vue --auth
```

Comment: hola actualicé el post realicé lo que me indicaste, añadí una imagen sigue el error. Gracias